# how to post html field arrays in forms using php

Tags: php, sql, model-view-controller, opencart

I have a form having 2 fields .

```
 <td class="left"><input style="  width: 30%; text-align: center;" type="text" name="name[]" value="<?php echo $geo_zone['name']; ?>" /></td>
 <td class="left"><input style="  width: 30%; text-align: center;" type="email" name="email[]" value="<?php echo $geo_zone['email']; ?>" /></td>
```

if i print_r my arrays i get perfect result. like this

```
$name = $this->request->post['name'];;
$email = $this->request->post['email'];;
```

but what i want is to keep inserting these two values in database until arrays are empty ($name and $email).For this i tried for each loop but it only inserts one row in database.

```
 foreach( $name as $key => $n ) {

    $this->data['geo_zone_id']=$this->model_module_shipping_pools->Get_geo_zone_id($n);


    $geo_zone_id=$this->data['geo_zone_id'];
    $geo_zone_id=$geo_zone_id[0]['geo_zone_id'];

    $this->model_module_shipping_pools->drop_data();
    $email=$email[$key];

    $this->model_module_shipping_pools->insertData($geo_zone_id,$email);

    }
```

Comment: `but what i want is to keep inserting these two values in database until arrays are empty ($name and $email).`  Can you explain this more elaborately?

Comment: @anantkumarsingh actually my form is created dynamically based on the rows in database so these two email and name arrays may contain more than one values. u see only two input fields in html but they are generated on run time thats y i have used name[] and email[] to store multiple values

Comment: @anantkumarsingh any idea why my loop is running only one time

Answer (score 0):

`$email=$email[$key];` - you're overwriting your `$email` variable. Call it something else.

Comment: changed it to $mail and than passed to model function still one row. the last row always get inserted

Comment: any idea why my loop is running only one time

Comment: Can you var_dump $name and $email?

Comment: yes i get this result.. array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "Texas" [1]=> string(7) "Florida" } array(2) { [0]=> string(13) "abs@gmail.com" [1]=> string(13) "xyz@gmail.com" }